# how to get specific timestamp from telethon GetLocatedRequest for each request?

Tags: location, telegram, telethon

`I want to use the telethon GetLocatedRequest, but I noticed that if the user used the telethon "nearby" feature just before turning off his/her phone's location service, the telethon still shows him/her at the last location. But you know he/she can change the location during this time.

I think Telethon is saving somewhere when the user activates the "nearby" feature, so how can I get this time/timestamp? This will make my data more reliable.

Thank you`

You can see an example telegram GetLocatedRequest feature code below.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.contacts.GetLocatedRequest(
        geo_point=types.InputGeoPoint(
            lat=7.13,
            long=7.13,
            accuracy_radius=42
        ),
        self_expires=42
    ))
    print(result)
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telethon is not caching the result. It is the Telegram server. If Telegram does not include the data, you can only guess.

It's probably safer to not have such accurate location information available.